# How do i include inclusion exclusion principle and venn diagrams in this type of problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

I have to do a task where i need to create requirements for 3 different types of passwords and find its probability: my requirements are:

The password length has to be exactly 8 for each level

no characters can be repeated to include permutations and combinatorics

Low level: Only lower case letters and numbers and must contain at least one letter.

Medium Level: Lower case letters, Capital letters and numbers are allowed and must contain at least one of each.

High level: Lower case letters, capital letters, numbers and special characters are allowed and must contain at least one of each.

I have developed combinatorics cases for it and stuff but i need some way to incorporate venn diagrams and inclusion exclusion principle. IDK how to please someone help out.

its an entire task, but the goal is to make requirements for 3 different types of passwords and then use these requirements to find the number of possible combinations for it.

Anyways my requirements are above, by no characters can be repeated i mean that numbers, letters or special characters cannot be repeated in the pasword, there has to be only one of each. I wanna find some way to inclue venn diagrams into this.

Comment: What do you mean by "no characters can be repeated to include permutations and combinatorics"?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but this question that showed up in the "Related" sidebar (now under "Linked") is about passwords, Venn diagrams and inclusion–exclusion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142566

Comment: The first one is easy: the total number minus the number with just numbers.  The others are slightly more complicated but not much and you should show us what you have tried

Comment: Why do you want to include Venn diagrams? What do you hope for them to accomplish? Generally Venn diagrams are used to illustrate set overlaps to others. They are not really useful for solving problems like this. If you do want to communicate with them, fine, but we need a better idea of what and why before we can make helpful suggestions.